# Swing GUI for games (performance)

Tags: java, lwjgl, gui, slick, swing

I'm developing a game in Slick2D and I'm trying to make GUI.

I've already tried [TWL](http://twl.l33tlabs.org/) library, but it seems to me a bit complicated and it doesn't cover what I need. In my own implementation of GUI I've encountered a problem with positioning of components. That's why I'm interested in Swing. I would use only its layout system and I would render components on my own (in Slick render loop).

So I'm asking, is it good for performance to do so? May I encounter other problems with Swing?

Comment: GUIs are not really performance intense, so you should be fine not matter what. Unless you make some really, really weird code.

Comment: It is possible to have [a Slick2D game displaying in a canvas](http://slick.ninjacave.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/CanvasGameContainer.html).

Comment: @AlexandreDesbiens Yes, I've read about that, but I have bad experience with Canvas rendering. It's not good for performance, is it? Or this Slick implementation is better?

Comment: This is not about canvas rendering, it is about placing a Slick2D game inside a canvas. So you call all Slick2D's functions and it will use LWJGL and OpenGL, but it will be rendered in a canvas instead of an entire window.

Comment: @AlexandreDesbiens I'm getting this error, when I try to run the game: `org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Parent.isDisplayable() must be true`. I have had no component in canvas yet. Do I need to have a component in Canvas to run the Game?

Answer (score 1):

Swing should be fine for your needs.

You should check out [this stackexchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/47154/what-drawbacks-does-java-swing-gui-framework-have) for other possible problems with Swing.

Comment: Would you mind expanding your answer? Though this technically correct as far as answering the question, it doesn't provide any real body.

Answer (score 0):

For the most part, swing is very easy to learn. Swing itself is not a good developmental language for 2D based games, however, it can be used for minor GUI applications, such as the one you are talking about. I see no performance issues, just the Swing thread and the Slick2D thread may pose difficulty synchronizing, if that's what's needed.

Comment: Though this is a fairly good answer, it doesn't really answer THIS question. You may want to note that in the first sentence of the question, the OP states that he is already using Slick2D. He is asking about using Swing for just GUI, and not about what to use to make his game.

Comment: I see. If he's using Swing just for the layout, that is fine. I see no performance change with that happening.

Comment: _"Swing itself is not a good developmental language... "_ - Swing is not a language.